# Evaluate an expression stored in variable in jmeter using beanshell

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I've pulled an expression from SQL db and that expression is stored as String in jmeter beanshell assertion.
Now I would like to use that expression to evaluate different values

`String LeftTank_conv = vars.get("Conv_formula_5") + ""; LeftTank_conv = "{x*100*245/345;}"(something like this)`
how can I use this string as an expression to evaluate for different x values

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the possibility to evaluate arbitrary arithmetic formulae you could use [JEXL engine](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) which is being used in JMeter's [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) so I'll provide the example solution using Groovy syntax:

```
def context = new org.apache.commons.jexl3.MapContext()
context.set('x', 1)

def engine = new org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlBuilder().create()
def e = engine.createExpression(vars.get('Conv_formula_5'))

def result = e.evaluate(context)

log.info('Execution result: ' + result as String)
```

Demo:

[image]